# Sorting columns that are aggregating a reference ( e.g. sum)

Tags: react-admin

In react-admin, for one record in a data grid, I want to get the total number of a relation to that record, and then be able to sort it.

For example, let's say I have a join table for authors and followers. For the author list I want a column that tells me the total number of followers for this author. Then I want to sort that column so that I can see which authors have the most/least followers.

To get the "number of followers"-column I created a custom Component that can return the follower-count for each author:

```
const ReferenceCount = ({ reference, target }) => {
  const record = useRecordContext();
  const { total, isLoading, error } = useGetManyReference(reference, {
    target: target,
    id: record.id
    //sort: { field: "?", order: "DESC" }
  });
  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>loading...</p>;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <p>ERROR</p>;
  }
  return total;
};
```

and used it within a datagrid (source is authors):

```
  <List>
    <Datagrid>
      <TextField source="name" />

      <ReferenceCount
        reference="authorFollower"
        target="authorId"
        label="Number of Followers"
      />
       </Datagrid>
  </List>
```

It works! But the column is not sortable as the values are not related to any field. So I cannot add the sort property to the custom component, or use the `sortBy`-tag. It seems that the custom sort button also depends on a field.

Is there a any way to achieve this?

Comment: You are doing it wrong, as you can read in documentation of react-admin, the sortBy property referers to the property, used in the backend, necessary to sort data. This means that the sortBy is passed to the rest service that will sort data based on it. To achive this you have to handle "counts" server side based on query string.

Comment: @RobertoConteRosito, I'm sending the counts with `X-Total-Count` header, I'm pretty sure that's how they are supposed to be send. Are you saying I should also add the count to each record?